# Getting member of json object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spring-mvc

In my spring mvc application,below is a js object posting on mvc controller using jquery-ajax.

I want to access each js object as string in my controller for iteration. The jQuery ajax does a post on controller, but I cannot access member of json object array. How can I do that?

**js**

```
var arr = [];
    var index;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rating").click(function() {
            var idx = $(this).closest('td').index();

            var userskill = {
                tech : $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.tech').text(),
                skill : $('#listTable thead th').eq(idx).text(),
                rValue : $(this).val()

            }

        var result= containsObject(userskill,arr);
        if(result==false){
            arr.push(userskill);

        }else{
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            arr.push(userskill);
        }

    });
    });

    function containsObject(obj, list) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if ((list[i].tech === obj.tech) && (list[i].skill==obj.skill)) {
                    index=i;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : '/SimplWebApp/saveUserRating',
            data : ({
                id : JSON.stringify(arr)
            }),
            success : function(responseData) {
                if (responseData != null) {

                    alert(responseData);
                } else {
                    alert("no data");
                }
            }

        });
        });
    });
```

**controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "saveUserRating")
        public @ResponseBody String saveUserRating(
                @RequestParam(value = "id") String[] x) {

        //code here..!
            return x;
        }
```

i want to get data on controller like

```
String tech=.........
String skill=........
String rValue=.......
```

json

```
 ["[{\"tech\":\"core javaá\"","\"skill\":\"Training\"","\"rValue\"
:\"1\"}","{\"tech\":\"Hibernateá\"","\"skill\":\"Training\"","\"rValue\":\"3\"}"
,"{\"tech\":\"javaFXá\"","\"skill\":\"Training\"","\"rValue\":\"2\"}]"]
```

Comment: Can you post the json data that is actually sent over HTTP from the client to the Spring MVC controller?

Comment: Don't duplicate your own question to give it attention.

Comment: @Bart its not a duplicate question..read my question  heading and comment..possible two objectives of 2 question.

Comment: In my eyes it is. Having another title and adding some additional info doesn't make it another question. The intention is the same.

Comment: @Bart 2 codes are same ,but questions are different.Hope u understand.